# Консоль в Windows

Tags: windows, консоль

Не удается указать в консоли нужную директорию. Методом научного тыка узнал, что если название директории меньше 8 символов то всё ок, если 8 и больше, то пишет "неправильный каталог". Она что - действительно не видит папки с названием длинней восьми символов?!

Comment: Какой то бред...Может с символами типа пробела или тире как то ошиблись? Потому что у меня к примеру редкость когда каталог назван меньше 6-8 символов. И если консоль не будет этого распознавать...

Comment: Ну вот путь, к примеру, Z:\\home\\yo\\www\\administrator\\components
- по кускам разбирал, матюкается именно на длинные. ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует ряд правил по именованию файлов и каталогов, возможно, вы нарушаете какие-либо из них: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx).

> Typically, Windows stores long file names on disk as special directory entries, which can be disabled systemwide for performance reasons depending on the particular file system.

На современных Windows (7 и старше) ограничение 8.3 редко когда проявляется.

Comment: win xp  у меня, вобщем непонятка какаято))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте путь поместить в кавычки.

В случае, если в пути пробелы без кавычек всё плохо.